# Github CLI Beta: How to view readme inside a folder

Tags: linux, windows, github, command-line-interface

I recently stumbled across [Github CLI Beta](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation-and-upgrading). It allows for viewing repos, cloning, forking, and creating repos all from the command line.

My question is the following: How can I view a readme that is inside a folder of a repo?

I can view this one:

> bhristov96/example_repo/README.md

How can I view this one?

> bhristov96/example_repo/src/README.md

The syntax to view the repo is the following:

```
gh repo view OWNER/REPO
```

Specifying anything further doesn't work:

```
gh repo view OWNER/REPO/FOLDER
```

Is there a different way to accomplish this, or is it just not supported yet?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the current [`cli/cli` `command/repo_test.go # TestRepoView`](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/39e6f412cbc73833323d87ac4e014f0168e48516/command/repo_test.go#L808-L834), I would say: not supported

You can see the [repoView() implementation](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/4d11732a474fb4651704f9d9876d9f627e4283b5/command/repo.go#L491-L589): it [uses](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/4d11732a474fb4651704f9d9876d9f627e4283b5/command/repo.go#L558)

```
readmeContent, _ := api.RepositoryReadme(apiClient, fullName)
```

And [`RepositoryReadme`](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/be5fc07928fdb42b927db319a954c62393c9f29a/api/queries_repo.go#L374-L403) is just a call to  the [GitHub Repository "Get README" API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-the-readme)

So it is for now limited to the official README (at the root of your repository)

But it would not be such a stretch to propose another function which would call the [Get contents API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents), with any path you want as a parameter.